# How can I use Arc in seeds.exs

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to seed my project, but I keep getting the error below whenever I try to run the seeds.exs. Some of my attributes use the ARC dependency for file uploads and this is what is causing my error. I do not understand how I am not matching any function clauses for Arc.Ecto.Type.dump.

```
Repo.insert! Show.changeset(%Show{
  title: "NP News",
  position: 1,
  showimageurl: %Plug.Upload{filename: "file.jpg", path: "http://example.com/file.jpg"},
  lcrshowimageurl: %Plug.Upload{filename: "file.jpg", path: "http://example.com/file.jpg"},
  shuffleepisodes: true
})
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
 ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Arc.Ecto.Type.dump/2
(arc_ecto) lib/arc_ecto/type.ex:39: Arc.Ecto.Type.dump(Project.LcrShowImageUploader, %Plug.Upload{content_type: nil, filename: "file.jpg", path: nil})
(ecto) lib/ecto/type.ex:629: Ecto.Type.do_adapter_dump/3
(ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:625: Ecto.Repo.Schema.dump_field!/6
(ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:638: anonymous fn/6 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.dump_fields!/5
(stdlib) lists.erl:1263: :lists.foldl/3
(ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:636: Ecto.Repo.Schema.dump_fields!/5
(ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:585: Ecto.Repo.Schema.dump_changes!/6
(ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:190: anonymous fn/11 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
(ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:614: anonymous fn/3 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.wrap_in_transaction/6
(ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:508: anonymous fn/3 in Ecto.Adapters.SQL.do_transaction/3
(db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1063: DBConnection.transaction_run/4
(db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:987: DBConnection.run_begin/3
(db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:667: DBConnection.transaction/3
(ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:124: Ecto.Repo.Schema.insert!/4
(elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
(mix) lib/mix/tasks/run.ex:71: Mix.Tasks.Run.run/1
(mix) lib/mix/task.ex:296: Mix.Task.run_task/3
```

Anyone have any idea what I may be doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the new seeds.exs:

```
 alias TestCms.Repo
 alias TestCms.Show
 alias TestCms.Episode

 Repo.insert! Show.changeset(%Show{}, %{
     title: "NP News",
     position: 1,
     showimageurl: %Plug.Upload{filename: "file.jpg", path: "http://test.tv/RokuImages/MusicVideoImages/Emerald_RokuHD.jpg"},
     lcrshowimageurl: %Plug.Upload{filename: "file.jpg", path: "http://test.tv/RokuImages/MusicVideoImages/Emerald_RokuHD.jpg"},
     shuffleepisodes: true
 })
```

Here is the new error I am getting:

```
  ** (Ecto.InvalidChangesetError) could not perform insert because changeset is invalid.

  * Changeset changes

  %{position: 1, shuffleepisodes: true, title: "NP News"}

  * Changeset params
   %{"lcrshowimageurl" => {%Plug.Upload{content_type: nil, filename:   "file.jpg",    path: "http://test.tv/RokuImages/MusicVideoImages/Emerald_RokuHD.jpg"}, %TestCms.Show{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "shows">, episodes: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :episodes is not loaded>, id: nil, inserted_at: nil, lcrshowimageurl: nil, position: 1, showimageurl: nil, shuffleepisodes: true, title: "NP News", updated_at: nil}}, "position" => 1, "showimageurl" => {%Plug.Upload{content_type: nil, filename: "file.jpg", path: "http://test.tv/RokuImages/MusicVideoImages/Emerald_RokuHD.jpg"}, %TestCms.Show{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "shows">, episodes: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :episodes is not loaded>, id: nil, inserted_at: nil, lcrshowimageurl: nil, position: 1, showimageurl: nil, shuffleepisodes: true, title: "NP News", updated_at: nil}}, "shuffleepisodes" => true, "title" => "NP News"}

  * Changeset errors

  [showimageurl: {"is invalid", [type: TestCms.ShowImageUploader.Type]}, lcrshowimageurl: {"is invalid", [type: TestCms.LcrShowImageUploader.Type]}]

 (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:127: Ecto.Repo.Schema.insert!/4
 (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
 (mix) lib/mix/tasks/run.ex:71: Mix.Tasks.Run.run/1
 (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:296: Mix.Task.run_task/3
 (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:58: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
 (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
```

Here is the Show module:

```
 defmodule TestCms.Show do
   use TestCms.Web, :model
   use Arc.Ecto.Schema

   schema "shows" do
     field :title, :string
     field :position, :integer
     field :showimageurl, TestCms.ShowImageUploader.Type
     field :lcrshowimageurl, TestCms.LcrShowImageUploader.Type
     field :shuffleepisodes, :boolean, default: false
     has_many :episodes, TestCms.Episode

     timestamps()
   end

   @doc """
   Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
   """
   def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
     struct
     |> cast(params, [:title, :position, :shuffleepisodes])
     |> cast_attachments(params, [:showimageurl, :lcrshowimageurl])
     |> validate_required([:title, :position, :showimageurl, :lcrshowimageurl,    :shuffleepisodes])
     |> unique_constraint(:position)
   end

   def search(query, search_term) do
     from s in query,
       where: fragment("similarity(?, ?) > ?", s.title, ^search_term, 0.1),
       order_by: fragment("similarity(?, ?) DESC", s.title, ^search_term)
   end
 end
```

Comment: Does this work? `Show.changeset(%Show{}, %{ title: "NP News", ... })`? If not, can you post the source of `Show.changeset`?

Comment: @dogbert If I change it to that, It says it "expected params to be a map".

Comment: @dogbert `def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:title, :position, :shuffleepisodes])
    |> cast_attachments(params, [:showimageurl, :lcrshowimageurl])
    |> validate_required([:title, :position, :showimageurl, :lcrshowimageurl, :shuffleepisodes])
    |> unique_constraint(:position)
  end`

Comment: Are you sure you passed the second argument as `%{...}` and _not_ `%Show{...}`?

Comment: Looks like storing the file may be failing. Can you double check Arc configuration? See https://github.com/stavro/arc_ecto/blob/7c17544d438ce914feadaea7535de2c0d4928f9d/test/schema_test.exs#L57-L62.

Comment: @Dogbert I am not seeing anything. I did notice duplicate Show params in the changeset params error. I added the new error above. Is that of significance?

Comment: Can you also post the exact code of the function which calls `Show.changeset` and throws this new error?

Comment: @Dogbert Notice anything odd?